# How can I interpret this stacktrace

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, crashlytics, stack-trace

I am seeing some crashes that I cannot properly read.

Background: The app has a react native part. Below the regular react native objc code with some additional modules. The there is lot of custom objc and swift code. And on the very bottom we have a c/c++ engine doing their voodoo.

Note: Those stack traces are taken from Firebase / Crashlytics. Are these logs looking like DSYM files are missing? Or am I just not able to read them?

## First stacktrace

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Objc/C++Part                   0x104052a6c Engine::setTask(Task const*) + 408
1  SwiftPart                      0x102dc14a8 __swift_memcpy2_1 + 3268
2  SwiftPart                      0x102d89c2c globalinit_33_D059BB15480DF7E417659EA3E0158837_func83 + 2880
3  SwiftPart                      0x102dc6a28 globalinit_33_164233930FF8443B67F99609B74287FF_func109 + 496
4  SwiftPart                      0x102dc2ff4 globalinit_33_F9D0611596767A886B653DD36AB555FE_func108 + 2208
5  Foundation                     0x196131050 __NSFireTimer + 64
6  CoreFoundation                 0x195cc5e00 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
7  CoreFoundation                 0x195cc5b3c __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 880
8  CoreFoundation                 0x195cc520c __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 276
9  CoreFoundation                 0x195cc0348 __CFRunLoopRun + 1920
10 CoreFoundation                 0x195cbf8a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
11 GraphicsServices               0x19fc17328 GSEventRunModal + 104
12 UIKitCore                      0x199db0740 UIApplicationMain + 1936
13 MainApplication                0x1023390e4 main + 16 (main.m:16)
14 libdyld.dylib                  0x195b4a360 start + 4
```

**What does the line** `2  SwiftPart  0x102d89c2c globalinit_33_D059BB15480DF7E417659EA3E0158837_func83 + 2880` **mean for example? How can I find out what line `Engine::setTask(Task const*) + 408` exactly means?**

## Second stacktrace

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1aba7b440 swift_isUniquelyReferenced_nonNull_native + 34
1  MainApplication                0x100bb6f60 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4309315424 (<compiler-generated>:4309315424)
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x19e18b7dc _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 104
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x19e1d9184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x19e18b190 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1044
5  CoreFoundation                 0x19e48a5e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
6  CoreFoundation                 0x19e4855d8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2004
7  CoreFoundation                 0x19e484adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
8  GraphicsServices               0x1a840a328 GSEventRunModal + 104
9  UIKitCore                      0x1a257fae0 UIApplicationMain + 1936
10 MainApplication                0x100b310e4 main + 16 (main.m:16)
11 libdyld.dylib                  0x19e30e360 start + 4
```

**Same here. How to read this?**

Comment: Inside the Engine class, in the setTask method, look down 408 lines in the code

Comment: @johnelemans the file only has 305 lines

Comment: If possible, breakpoint that method and walk it.

Comment: I can't repro the issue. It's just this logs I have

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006622/exc-bad-access-in-swift-isuniquelyreferenced-nonnull-native-when-accessing-swift

Comment: @ZmicierZaleznicenka interestingly both questions are from my end but are a bit different

Comment: @MartinMlostek did you find anything on this?