# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in swift_isUniquelyReferenced_nonNull_native when accessing swift array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-management, exc-bad-access

#### The Problem

While writing unit tests and mocking away the `NSTimer` I am seeing an

```
Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
```

inside

```
swift_isUniquelyReferenced_nonNull_native
```

The situation appear when accessing the array `invalidateInvocations` (inside `func invalidate()`) here.

```
class TimerMock: Timer {

    /// Timer callback type
    typealias TimerCallback = ((Timer) -> Void)

    /// The latest used timer mock accessible to control
    static var  currentTimer: TimerMock!

    /// The block to be invoked on a firing
    private var block:        TimerCallback!

    /// Invalidation invocations (will contain the fireInvocation indices)
    var invalidateInvocations: [Int] = []

    /// Fire invocation count
    var fireInvocations:       Int   = 0

    /// Main function to control a timer fire
    override open func fire() {
        block(self)
        fireInvocations += 1
    }

    /// Hook into invalidation
    override open func invalidate() {
        invalidateInvocations.append(fireInvocations)
    }

    /// Hook into the timer configuration
    override open class func scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval interval: TimeInterval,
                                            repeats: Bool,
                                            block: @escaping TimerCallback) -> Timer {
        // return timer mock
        TimerMock.currentTimer = TimerMock()
        TimerMock.currentTimer.block = block
        return TimerMock.currentTimer
    }

}
```

The interesting thing is if I change `invalidateInvocations` to a regular `Int` it can be accessed without any crashes.

Because accessing this variable leads to a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` I would assume the array was already deallocated, but I would not see how this could happen.

#### The Demo

You can see a full running and crashing example in this repository (branch `demo/crash`)

https://github.com/nomad5modules/ArcProgressViewIOS/tree/demo/crash

Simply execute the unit tests and see it crashing.

#### The Question

What is happening here? I have observed a crash inside `swift_isUniquelyReferenced_nonNull_native` already in other projects too and I would love to completely understand the reason for this failure! So how is the process to find out what wrong here? And how to fix it?

#### Standalone reproduction project

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fMGhgpmBRG6hzpaiTM9lO_zCZwNhwIpx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think the problem is not about `swift_isUniquelyReferenced_nonNull_native` because you can't access `invalidateInvocations` anyway, if you try to print `invalidateInvocations` crash will appear.

Comment: Thats true, simply accessing the array leads to a crash. Any idea why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The crash is due to not initialised member (it is NSObject not regular swift class, so explicit init() would be needed, but as this is Timer it has semi-abstract designated initializer, so override is not allowed).

The solution is to set up missed ivar explicitly, as below.

Tested & works on your Test project with Xcode 11.4.

```
override open class func scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval interval: TimeInterval,
                                        repeats: Bool,
                                        block: @escaping TimerCallback) -> Timer {
    // return timer mock
    TimerMock.currentTimer = TimerMock()
    TimerMock.currentTimer.invalidateInvocations = [Int]()   // << fix !!
    TimerMock.currentTimer.block = block
    return TimerMock.currentTimer
}
```

Comment: did you try that code with the given repository? same error happening

Comment: @MartinMlostek, repository code is no compilable at my side. Would you provide some standalone demo code in question?

Comment: oh. okay. but i wonder why its not compatible? it should be just, clone, pod install (its just a local pod) and then run the tests

Comment: i have updated the question. here is a standalone mac application that is just the code form the repo copy pasted as a mac terminal app https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fMGhgpmBRG6hzpaiTM9lO_zCZwNhwIpx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Great. its working. But can you explain a bit more detailed why the initialization inside the class does not work?

Comment: @MartinMlostek, Timer is bridged objective-c NSObject kind class, so it's initialization have to follow objective-c rules, and in that world only primitive type properties got default values, array is not primitive for objective-c, so skipped, thus corresponding property was uninitialised - accessing not initialised property in run-time result in crash.

Comment: @Asperi, any idea why this is not a problem with other NSObject subclasses? Like UIViewController?